# select one item from array stored in redux

Tags: redux

I want to render only one item from an array stored in `redux`.
For example, let's say my stored array is as follow:

```
[
  {item1: 1},
  {item2: 2}
]
```

I thought I could target item at index 0 like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userInput: state.userInput.datas[0]
});
```

However, it still returns the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I thought:

Instead of targeting an array item in mapStateToProps, i passed it as an argument when dispatching my thunk.

e.g:
`this.props.dispatch(fetchSubGroup(this.props.userInput[0]));`